# Update cells in a row based on values within a range in a column on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, range

I am trying to search through Column D on Sheet 1 and grabbing values that are within a certain range (10-100) and getting them to populate onto Sheet 2 in a row (ex: Row 20) and skipping the values that are not within the range without leaving a gap/blank cell in the results. However, the newest value overwrites the old cell values (so instead of having 10, 11, 12 on Sheet 2, it is just 12, 12, 12). Additionally, I have not been able to figure out how to get the values to populate in a single row (Like Row C3:Z3) so they have been populating in a column instead.

Method 1:

```
Sub SearchLoop

Range("Sheet1!D").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
If ActiveCell.Value > 10 And ActiveCell.Value < 100 
Then Range("Sheet2!A:A").Value = Selection.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
End Sub
```

Method2:

```
Sub SearchLoop

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell in Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
If cell.Value > 10 And cell.Value < 100 Then
Range("Sheet2!A").Value = cell.Value

End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: If without loop is OK with you, maybe you can try to filter column D, copy the visible cell then paste to sheet2 starting at cell A1. Something like this : `With Sheet1.Range("D1:D" & Rows.Count): .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=1", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=100": .SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1"): .AutoFilter Field:=1: End With`.

Comment: Oops... sorry just noticed that you want to get the result in sheet2 is one row instead one columns... so `.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy: Sheet2.Range("A20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:=True` this will paste the result to row 20 starting from column A.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub CopyValuesInRange()
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dstColumn As Long
    
    
    ' Find the last row in column D of Sheet1
    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the source range in column D of Sheet1
    Set srcRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the source range
    For Each cell In srcRange
        If cell.Value > 10 And cell.Value < 100 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A20").Offset(0, dstColumn).Value = cell.Value
            ' Increment the destination column
            dstColumn = dstColumn + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```